GRUB doesn't load to menu
I have installed Ubuntu 22.04 next to Windows 11. After I extended my main disk I cant seem to load in GRUB2 Menu (Before i was able to) I found a disk (hd0,gpt1) which has grub.cfg. I have tried doing some fixes about setting prefix giving root to disk but doesnt seem to fix In the disk I found it has efi/ubuntu the cfg file is in ubuntu folder. Im not sure if its the grub folder/path and it has a folder named boot I dont know if it's the folder too?
While I was trying to fix it gave error something like no such device

You may want to try the boot-repair utility. It will generate a report and upload it for sharing. Edit your question and add that link to share the boot repair report. Do not do the "Do Standard Repair" yet.
